# Cannot debug VSTO addin on terminal server

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin

Our development team mostly works on the same terminal server.  We are working on an Outlook VSTO 2010 addin.  We just migrated from "Visual Studio 2008/Office 2003/VSTO 2005" to "Visual Studio 2010/Office 2010/VSTO 2010".  Attempting to debug the Add-In from Visual Studio results in the following error if any other user is running Outlook on the server:

Cannot debug the add-in because 'Outlook' is already running. Close 'Outlook' and then run the project again.

Before the software update, each developer could debug the app at the same time.  Any ideas on a cause/solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A co-worker was able to find a solution:

Add Outlook.exe to the Visual Studio solution as an existing project, by browsing to the Office installation path from the “Add existing project” dialog, and selecting Outlook.exe.

Set the Outlook project as the StartUp project.

Set the Outlook project Debugger Type to “Managed v4.0”.

This allows debugging to work as it did before, but skips the existing process check that was added to VSTO.

Comment: How does one set the "Outlook project Debugger Type" to "Managed v4.0"? Clicking on the outlook.exe project to set its properties generates an error. I'm trying this out because in VS 2013, trying to debug an outlook 2007 add-in. It's been working fine forever, and all of a sudden it keeps refusing to debug. I'm sure restarting the machine would resolve the issue but I am working remotely and cannot reboot for a week. Restarting visual studio and outlook has not worked.

Comment: Right now just running the Outlook.exe project runs outlook, but does not step into the managed code (or stop at breakpoints in the managed code)