# Cannot debug the add-in because 'Outlook' is already running

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook 2007 add-in project in Visual Studio 2013. It's been working fine forever, and all of a sudden Visual Studio keeps refusing to debug, with an error message saying

> Cannot debug the add-in because 'Outlook' is already running. Close
> 'Outlook' and then run the project again.

No, outlook is not running. There is no Outlook process visible in the processes tab of Task Manager.

I'm sure restarting the machine would resolve the issue but I am working remotely and cannot reboot for a week. Restarting visual studio and outlook has not worked. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127042/68936) but as I noted in my comment to the answer, breakpoints don't get triggered.

How does Visual Studio check for running outlook?

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that Outlook is showing up as a 'suspended' process in Task Manager, in the 'details' tab (it does not show up in the processes tab, which is where I looked before). How can I resume the suspended outlook (right-clicking on it does not show an option to resume), and how do I prevent outlook from being suspended?

Comment: I was able to resume outlook from the resource monitor. After resuming it and shutting it down, debugging the outlook add in worked fine. Still don't know how it got suspended, and how to prevent it from getting suspended again (I don't think it's anything *I* did to suspend it?)

Comment: That's interesting, never knew that possibility existed.  Usually when I see a suspended app, it's because it crashed or the attached debugger crashed, or I forcibly stopped debugging.  At that point I would've just rebooted the system.  Maybe WER was latched onto the zombie process.  You can reboot your system remotely if necessary, either as local from as Remote Desktop, or from your remote machine, [see TechNet doco for `shutdown`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx), the only this is, make sure you get the **switches correct**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook was running as a suspended process. It could not be seen in the 'processes' tab of Task Manager; I found it in the 'details' tab. It was misleading because I could still start (manually a new instance of) Outlook and shut it down and yet Visual Studio kept reporting that Outlook was already running. Anyway, I was able to resume the suspended instance of Outlook from Resource Monitor (which can be opened from Task Manager's 'Performance' tab (hyperlink at the bottom that says 'Open Resource Monitor'). After resuming the suspended Outlook process and shutting it down, debugging the outlook add in worked fine.